# How can +2 websites benefit in a partnership aside from backlink exchange?

Tags: seo, networking

Website owners with the same target but different services can help each other grow. Are there methods other than linking to each other that could produce SEO benefits?

Answer (score 1):

Nowadays, links exchanges are almost useless because too much under radar of search engines.
However, you can choose one site to optimize and put links to it from the second one.

Comment: Are they still useless when the exchangers have similar content?

Comment: Yes, it's useless for SEO (maybe not for your visitors) and can even have nagative impacts.

Comment: Do you have a reference? I'd like to read more about that. Google officially says not to use excessive links but doesn't specify DOs and DONTs.

Comment: For example, [this article](http://www.brickmarketing.com/blog/link-exchanges-bad.htm).

Answer (score 0):

They can do following

1. Engage in Social Media
2. Write content for each other
3. Review each others product/services

Don't just think from SEO point of view only, there is more to it